Normal vector implicitly defined by two equations
I have two equations:
$$
f(x,y,z_1,z_2) = 0,\\
g(x,y,z_1,z_2) = 0
$$
for two functions of interest $z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2(x,y)$.
These functions are multivalued and I want to find where the "cusp" is where one solution transitions to another. To find the cusp, I know I need find the z-component of the normal to the surface and let it equal zero i.e. However, I don't know how to take the gradient wrt $x,y,z$ when there are two different equation defining the surfaces.
Can anyone help?
Edit:
An example of the above is:
$$
\sin(_1)+\log(_1+_2)=0,\\
(_1 _2)+\exp(_1+_2)=0,
$$
Ted Shifrin in the comments below explained that these each represent 3-d hypersurfaces in $\mathbb R^4$.
Numerically, I know that $z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2(x,y)$ are multi-valued.
I want to try and find the curve $y = p(x)$ where the two branches of the $z_1(x,y)$ surface are equal.

The notation you're using doesn't make sense to me. You're considering two $3$-dimensional hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^4$ which intersect in $z_1=z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2=z_2(x,y)$?

I just mean two surfaces each of which are functions of x and y. But each surface is not independent. Each surface is 2-dimensional and each surface lives in $\mathbf R^3$ at coordinates $(x,y,z_i(x,y))$ for $i = 1,2$.

Your language is not precise enough to make sense to me. By a "surface" which is a function of $x$ and $y$, you mean the surface is (locally?) the graph of a function, i.e., $z=\phi(x,y)$? For example, you could have $f(x,y,z)=x^2+y^2+z^2-1=0$ with $z_1=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and $z_2=-\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$? The sentence "each surface is not independent" means nothing to me.

I mean somehing like:
$$
x\sin(z_1) + y \log(z_1+ z_2) = 0,\
x(z_1 z_2) + y \exp(z_1+ z_2) = 0,
$$
where  $z_1 = z_1(x,y)$ and $z_2 = z_2(x,y)$

These are in fact $3$-dimensional hypersurfaces in $\Bbb R^4$, not surfaces in $\Bbb R^3$. The intersection is the single $2$-dimensional surface given by $(x,y,z_1(x,y),z_2(x,y))$. I guess you want to plot $z=z_1(x,y)$ and $z=z_2(x,y)$ in $\Bbb R^3$, but I'm not sure what you mean by transitioning ... Please do some editing of the original question, including this example in the actual question, and addressing my confusion(s).

Thanks for the clarification Ted. I hope the above is clearer.
